go ; package: command-line-arguments golang.org/x/net/websocket import loop
im attempting to set up noVNC-audio-master
which to run requires [go] and then requires you create a go.mod file for websocket
but, after running the command, this is the output:
User@Device:~/Downloads/noVNC-audio-master$ go run main.go --static ./static --vncAddress localhost:5900 --udpAddress :1234
package command-line-arguments
    imports golang.org/x/net/websocket
    imports golang.org/x/net/websocket: import cycle not allowed

i saw that command-line-arguments was the issue, but it turns out i have no idea what that is, even when looking at another stackoverflow answer. but, i can tell that websocket may be trying to import itself? anyways here's the commands i used chronologically:
sudo apt install golang-go  # version 2:1.18~0ubuntu2
go mod init golang.org/x/net/websocket
go mod tidy
go run main.go --static ./static --vncAddress localhost:5900 --udpAddress :1234

The commands declare main.go's module as golang.org/x/net/websocket.   The file main.go imports golang.org/x/net/websocket.  That's a circular reference.
Fix by declaring the main.go's module as something other than a package imported directly or indirectly by main.go.  Try these commands:
go mod init example.com/deeznuts
go mod tidy
go run main.go --static ./static --vncAddress localhost:5900 --udpAddress :1234

